# Bootstrap Affix not working after loading more content to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, affix

I have a web application using Bootstrap 3.2 and a menu with the [`Affix`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) enabled. this works fine in most scenarios except one:
I have an image gallery page where images are loaded "on the fly" when the user scrolls down - as soon as any image is added the affix breaks and does not revert the menu to `affix-top` when scrolling back to the top.

See [THIS](http://www.bootply.com/phyeDFHQD2) fiddle (don't make the screen to big):

- Scroll just as much down that the affix is set
- Scroll back to the top
  ==> working (yellow margin for `MENU ITEM` is restored):

[image: description]

Then do the following:

- Scroll to the bottom so some text is added
- Scroll back up
  ==> the `MENU ITEM` keeps beeing `affix`ed and sticks to the top:

[image: disc]

**Does someone know why this is happening or how I can fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(window).unbind('scroll');` is causing the issue, as the Bootstrap implementation likely relies on a scroll listener. Instead, make your scroll listener into a variable and use `$(window).off('scroll', scrollListener)` to remove only that listener.

see: [BootPly](http://www.bootply.com/SJWmltahEF)